# How to resize square button responsively?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to create a square button with bootstrap classes. However. It is only auto resizing horizontally. The height does not resize and retains its original size when i resize the browser. How can i achieve resizing these buttons horizontally and vertically?

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <a href="@Url.Action("Axis","Department")" id="axisBtn" class="btn btn-sq btn-info btn-block">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <a href="@Url.Action("Engineering","Department")" id="engBtn" class="btn btn-sq btn-default btn-block">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <a href="@Url.Action("Affect","Department")" id="affectBtn" class="btn btn-sq btn-default btn-block">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

.btn-sq {
    width: 300px;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: do you set height container of button?

Comment: @PajarFathurrahman yes i tried to set the height. but it is doing the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file called **responsive.css** and add it to your styles. It's good practice to add this file after other css files as you want these rules to take priority over your other css rules.

This would be the content of your responsive.css

```
/* Style for Extra Large Screen */
@media (max-width:1199px) {
    .btn-sq {
        width: 300px;
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        height: 300px;
    }
}

/* Style for Large Screen */
@media (max-width:991px) {
    .btn-sq {
        width: 300px; 
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        height: 300px;
    }
}

/* Style for Medium Screen */
@media (max-width:767px) {
    .btn-sq {
        width: 200px; /* whatever width you want for medium screen */
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        height: 150px; /* whatever height you want for medium screen */
    }
}

/* Style for Small Screen */
@media (max-width:575px) {
    .btn-sq {
        width: 200px; /* whatever width you want for mobile screen */
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        height: 150px; /* whatever height you want for mobile screen */
    }
}
```

This way, depending on your screen size, one of these sections will be selected and applied to you HTML.